# HOw to get user id in intranet MVC applicaiton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 site, authenticaiton is configured for intranet.

Now, i want to get logged in UserID,

How to fetch the user ID at some common place when accessing any first action (on particular user session) ?

Also, how to fetch User ID existed in context ?

Currently, i wrote session set logic `User.Identity.Name` on each controller index action.
Is this possible to move that logic for session set into some common place ?

Comment: First try and tell us what you have tried. Post code if you can.

Comment: Asp.Net Identity or SimpleMembership? Or custom?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for confusion.

Got the solutio. Created Action Filter as below and applied at each controller as attribute so, that code execute each time and i added relatd stuff at this place:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ControllerLogAndAccessFilter : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {


     }
```